# Display screensaver before user logs off

Tags: windows, registry, logout

I want to display screensaver for 1 minute when user logs out and after one minute user should automatically gets logged off. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Logoff screen saver can be used with the Windows Exit Screen Saver tool to lock the server when a user that has logged on to the server does not use the server for a set period of time. This feature must be configured for every user. To configure a default user profile to avoid the need for individual configurations

I add some link to help you
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297267

and this [log off screensaver with registry](http://www.upgradenrepair.com/Instructions/L/logoffscreensaver.htm)

and this link will help you to instaling logoff screensaver
[installation screen saver](http://www.mcgelec.com/Logoffss/installation.asp)

i hope one of them will help you.